# Python: inserting an item to the stack

Tags: python

I tried to insert an item into the stack but the size is still empty is the input inserted into the stack in this case?

Overtime i obtain the size of the stack/list it is Empty

```
def main_menu():
        print('\nMenu:')
        print('1. Push')

        the_stack = Stack()

        while True:
                try:
                    command = int(input("\nEnter command:"))
                    if command == 1:
                        try:
                            ask = int(input("\nEnter an integer:"))
                            the_stack = Stack()
                            the_stack.push(ask)
                            print("item pushed")
                            print(the_stack.peek())

                        except ValueError:
                            print ("Enter Integer numbers only")
                except ValueError:
                    print ('Please input a Number only')
                else:
                    if 1 <= command < 5:
                        break
                    else:
                        print ('Enter command from 1 to 4 only')

class Node:
    """
    The Node used for Linked List
    """
    def __init__(self, item, link):
        self.item = item
        self.next = link

class Stack:

    def push(self, item):
        self.top = Node(item, self.top)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_menu()
    the_stack = Stack()
```

Comment: Python does not have a builtin `Stack` class. You did not post your implementation of it, and you missed a proper error description as well.

Comment: At least your other question had the rest of the code in it...this one makes no sense on its own. Also, there's nothing wrong with the input, so focus on the push logic you've come up with.

Comment: Currently Its because the item is pushed into the stack but the size is still empty and i don't know why

Comment: It is impossible to tell what's happening without see the class `Stack`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list as stack in python:
Just Try this one.

```
    the_stack = []
    ask = int(input("Enter an integer:"))
    the_stack.append(ask)
    print("Item Added")
```

you can add as many item as you want to this by just using for loop.
To delete an item from this.
Use

```
    the_stack.pop()
```

It will remove the last added item from your list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any Stack method in Python.

but you can use list as a stack. Refer below link -

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks